Low-latency RTSP stream using OpenCV and ffmpeg seems to ignore flags
I'm writing a Qt6 application in C++ which should display and optionally store mutltiple RTSP streams. Currently, I'm using OpenCV to capture the stream:
m_capture = new cv::VideoCapture("rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.108:504/stream", cv::CAP_FFMPEG);
if (!m_capture->isOpened()) {
    //Error
}

cv::Mat frame;
m_abort = false;
while(!m_abort) 
{
    if (!m_capture->read(frame)) 
    {
        //Error
        return;
    }

    doStuff(frame);
}


This works, but has a delay of about 3 seconds for one of the streams.
Using this ffplay command in the terminal works without noticable delay, though:
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -rtsp_transport tcp "rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.108:504/stream"

I've tried to pass forward these flags without luck:
setenv("OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS","rtsp_transport;tcp|fflags;nobuffer|flags;low_delay",1);

Other than that, I have tried (as suggetested e.g. here)

using QMediaPlayer
setting the cv::VideoCapture cv::CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE to 3
using grab() and retrieve() instead of read()

TL;DR: How can I disable buffering in the OpenCV FFMPEG backend for RTSP streams to reduce latency in my Qt application?
I'm also open to entirely different approaches (e.g. using QMultiMedia), but haven't found a way to reduce latency with those either.

use ffmpeg's libraries directly.

That's what I'm currently trying :)
